# Guice assisted injection for typed classes

Tags: java, guice

I am trying to do assisted injection in Guice.

Here are my implementations.

```
public interface Dao<T> {
    T get(String id);
}

public class DaoImpl<T> implements Dao<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    DaoImpl(@Assisted final Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override 
    public T get() {
      //Some impl code
      return T;
    }
}
```

Factory interface.

```
public interface DaoFactory {
    <T> Dao<T> getDao(Class<T> clazz);
}
```

Guice module:

```
public class DaoModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
                .implement(new TypeLiteral<Dao<? extends Entity>>() {},
                        new TypeLiteral<DaoImpl<? extends Entity>>() {})
                .build(DaoFactory.class));
    }
}
```

I am getting error: "DaoFactory cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified".

How should I be configuring the FactoryModuleBuilder?

My objective is to obtain a typed instance of Dao at runtime using DaoFactory

Answer (score 0):

Assisted inject expects there to be a binding in place to select what you want to get returned to you - the parameters to your Factory interface must be just `@Assisted`-annotated parameters in the constructor of the desired implementation.

In this case, this means that in order for `DaoFactory.getDao` to take a `T`, then `DaoImpl<T>`'s constructor would need to take that `T` instance (annotated with `@Assisted`), and then that this would be enough somehow for that `DaoImpl` instance to be able to correctly build instances. Something like this, perhaps:

```java
public class DaoImpl<T> implements Dao<T> {

    public DaoImpl(@Assisted T instance) {
        // Do something with the instance so this Dao is wired up right.
        // perhaps with instanceof or instance.getClass()?
    }

    @Override 
    public T get() {
      //Some impl code
      return T;
    }
}
```

That's all assisted inject knows how to do - it isn't magic that can create runtime lookups somehow, but this might be enough for you, depending on your use case. I'm not sure why `DaoFactory.getDao` would take an instance of `T`, and then `Dao.get()` would then return a `T` as well, but as that is part of the sample code in the question, I'm guessing you have this planned out already.

---

Update after the edit:

`DaoFactory.getDao` takes a `T` instance, but the constructor for `DaoImpl` is `DaoImpl(@Assisted final Class<T> clazz)` - assisted inject factories must take the same parameter that is expected to be passed in to the constructor. This is good news for your question - you can simply change your factory declaration slightly:

```java
public interface DaoFactory {
    <T> Dao<T> getDao(Class<T> obj);
}
```

Now you call `getDao` with something like `MyEntity.class` as the parameter, and will be given a `Dao<MyEntity>` instance, which was created by guice internally calling `new DaoImpl(MyEntity.class)`.

If you want it specific to a some object, calling `instance.getClass()` and passing that in will have some generics effects you should understand, since `getClass()` actually returns a `Class<?>`, or at best a `Class<? extends WhateverMyDeclaredTypeIs>`. Consider the following:

```java
class MyClass {}
class MySubclass extends MyClass{}

MyClass foo = new MySubclass();

factory.getDao(foo.getClass());// the generics will be a Dao<? extends MyClass>, 
// not a Dao<MySubclass>, even though the DaoImpl.clazz holds an instance
// of MySubclass
```

Comment: I do have assisted params in the constructor. I have updated it above. In a class I want to have an instance of DaoFactory. I want to get an instance at runtime by passing a type. (At runtime, I want to get Dao<String> by doing factory.get(String.class)).

Comment: I tried this and getting error "DaoFactory cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified". I have updated the question with my Module and Factory changes